# Code 141 error Parse Twilio SMS cloud function

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, sms, twilio

My console is logging this error when I try to send an SMS to a phone:

```
   [Error]: Uh oh, something went wrong (Code: 141, Version: 1.7.1)
```

What is the problem? It's error 141 which is from what I understand a response.success inclusion-affiliated error, but honestly, I included response.success so it's not clear to me what the problem is here. Any help much appreciated.

Code in Xcode

```
 NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:number forKey:@"number"];
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendSMSVerification" withParameters:params block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
    NSString *message = @"";
    if (!error) {
        message = @"Your SMS invitation has been sent!";

    } else {
        message = @"Uh oh, something went wrong :(";
    }

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Verification Code sent!"
                                message:message
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];

}];
```

And the cloud function:

```
 // Include the Twilio Cloud Module and initialize it
    var twilio = require("twilio");
    twilio.initialize("****","*****"); //these are for testing; todo insert real ones when deploying

    // Create the Cloud Function
    Parse.Cloud.define("sendSMSVerification", function(request, response) {
      // Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS
     twilio.sendSMS({
    From: "1##########",
    To: request.params.number,
         Body: "test" //request.params.message//  SMS Verification: 1234 or    whatever the specific number is...
       }, {
        success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
        error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my cloud code which is working for me.

```
var client = require('twilio')('<Your Twilio Account Sid>', '<Your Twilio Auth Token>');

// Send an SMS message
client.sendSms(
        {
        to:'number',
        from: 'number',
        body: "Your verification code is " + verificationCode + "."
                              }, function(err,responseData) {
                              if (err) {
                              } else {
                              response.error(verificationCode);
                              }
                              }
                              );
               response.success(verificationCode);
               });
```

If you are using **FREE Twilio Account then make sure your number is verified by twilio.**

I follow [this tutorial](http://shamadeh.com/blog/web/mobile/twilio/parse/2014/07/31/VerifyPhoneNumbersTwilioAndParse.html) to send SMS and it worked for me. Try to follow this.

Hope this will help you.